# Using session storage instead of cookies

Tags: javascript, php, html, session, cookies

At the moment I am creating cookies in my website, In my api i create authorization string(HTTP BASIC), in my JavaScript, I am creating cookie, I have realised as this is a J Query mobile web based app, Cookies don't work on modern phones, I have researched and realised I need to HTML5 session storage, How do I convert the cookie code in that,and in headers it checks for auth cookie, how do I do that with session storage

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) { //create a cookie to store authorisation details on the clients machine
if (days) {

error: function (response) {
    var r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
    console.log(r);
    alert("Error:" + r.error.text);
               }
        });
}
```

Comment: what phone doesn't support cookies?

Comment: Iphone, android, when I try to access something that can only be accessed by logged in user, after logging in I still get the error that user must login, but that error doesn't occur on desktop

Comment: readCookie=sessionStorage.getItem.bind(sessionStorage); createCookie=sessionStorage.setItem.bind(sessionStorage);

Comment: Where do I add this line, and is that all I need?

Comment: So is this like PhoneGap/Cordova?

Comment: Yes it is like PhoneGap